# Two identical buttons but only one of them works

Tags: html, angularjs

The problem is basically outlined in the title. This app is built using Angular JS. I have two identical buttons stacked on top of each other in different divs in this HTML file and they both call the same function but with different parameters, however only one of the functions actually updates the desired value in the database. The other seems to do so at first but acts as if no change has happened once the page is reloaded. We are using an mLab database, and I have confirmed that the type parameter passed by the second function matches up to the field in the database.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <button class="btn farmerBtnGreen farmerMethod col-lg-6 col-md-offset-3" ng-click="emailFarmerAndAdmin(farmer,'organic')" ng-hide="farmer.organic == 1 || farmer.organic == 2">Start Organic Process</button>
    <button class="btn methodVerify col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2" ng-show="farmer.organic == 1" disabled>Processing Organic Verification</button>
    <button class ="btn methodVerified col-md-6 col-xs-offset-3" ng-show="farmer.organic == 2" disabled>Verified Organic</button>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <button class="btn farmerBtnGreen farmerMethod col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2" ng-click="emailFarmerAndAdmin(farmer,'conservationist')" ng-hide="farmer.conservationist == 1 || farmer.conservationist == 2">Start Conservationist Process</button>
    <button class="btn methodVerify col-lg-10 col-md-offset-1" ng-show="farmer.conservationist == 1" disabled>Processing Conservationist Verification</button>
    <button class ="btn methodVerified col-md-offset-3 col-xs-6" ng-show="farmer.conservationist == 2" disabled>Verified Conservationist</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.emailFarmerAndAdmin = function (farmer, type) {
  $scope.farmer[type] = 1
  $http({
      url: '/api/startVerify/' + JSON.stringify(farmer) + '/' + type,
      method: 'POST'
  }).success(function (data) {console.log(type}).error(function (data) {
      console.log("Error")
  });
};
```

Comment: You are setting `$scope.farmer[type] = 1` but you are passing only `farmer` to the api call. Is that intentional?

Comment: In the api call, type is concatenated onto the end of the url to specify which field should be modified

Comment: @OJRaqueño `farmer` *is* `$scope.farmer`.

Comment: Have you watched the network traffic in the Dev Console to verify the right request is going out?  The error is quite possibly server-side.

Comment: I just checked that out, it seems a request is being sent to the server but the response indicated that no changes were made: {"ok":0,"n":0,"nModified":0}

Comment: The functioning button returns this upon success: {"n":1,"nModified":1,"opTime":{"ts":"6544346917088788481","t":6},"electionId":"7fffffff0000000000000006","ok":1}